# card turn canvas draw

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

I want to have twelve (images of) cards facing down next to each other and be able to flip them when clicking on one. To display a random (image of a) card from a selection of twelve without repeating the same image twice.

Also whenever you click on a card I want to have a corresponding part of a numbered canvas to be accessible to draw on. This should continued till all cards are turned and all the areas are drawn.

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>game</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
      <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script>   <![endif]-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="html5-canvas-drawing-app.js">   </script>
      <script language="javascript">
         var imagesArray = [ 'images/img-1.jpg', 'images/img-2.jpg',
         'images/img-3.jpg', 'images/img-4.jpg', 'images/img-5.jpg',
         'images/img-6.jpg', 'images/img-7.jpg', 'images/img-8.jpg',
         'images/img-9.jpg', 'images/img-10.jpg', 'images/img-11.jpg',
         'images/img-12.jpg' ];

         var usedImages = {}; var usedImagesCount = 0;

         function displayImage(){

             var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));
             if (!usedImages[num]){
                 document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
                 usedImages[num] = true;
                 usedImagesCount++;
                 if (usedImagesCount === imagesArray.length){
                     usedImagesCount = 0;
                     usedImages = {};
                 }
             } else {
                 displayImage();
             } }


      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table border=0 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <tr align="center">
            <td><img src="images/blank.jpg" name="canvas" onClick="displayImage()"/></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <div id="canvasDiv"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() {
         prepareCanvas(); });
      </script>
      <a href="#" class="button" id="btn-download" download="my-file-name.png">Save</a>
      <script language="javascript"> var button = document.getElementById('btn-download');
         button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
             var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
             button.href = dataURL; });

      </script> 
   </body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out how to have all the cards face down at the start and how to select only past of the canvas for drawing in.

Comment: Depending on how to read your post, there is either no question at all, or more than one. You should reconsider what you actually want to ask.

Comment: Show us your HTML along with all javascript in a minimum working example to replicate the stage you are at now.

Comment: I reformatted your code so that it gets highlighted like code. Just to make it easier to read. :) Stack-overflow likes 4 spaces as appose to quoting.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this line: `document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];` I assume you were hoping to get this guy: `<img src="images/blank.jpg" name="canvas" onClick="displayImage()"/>` but that's not actually how you do that. The `name` attribute is for form elements. You use it to name the value that an input produces, not the html element itself. I think you wanted the `id` attribute, and I think you should use `document.getElementById("canvas")` instead.

Also, there isn't an actual html canvas in your example. I'm guessing `prepareCanvas` inserts it. You mentioned you wanted to only draw to one part of the canvas. Anytime you draw to an html5 canvas it will draw on top of anything that's already there. So if I want to only draw on one section, I can just draw on that section, and it will replace what was already there while leaving everything else alone. If you need to redraw a section, as in, wipe out what was there before replacing it, you can use [clearRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect). There is also something called "masking", but I don't think that's what you want. If you get really desperate, you might have to set up a "game loop" which continuously redraws the entire screen with the new state 60 times a second.

Comment: I fear I might not been clear enough what I want is to have this

Comment: <script>
    var clicks = 12; 

    var backcard = "images/blank.jpg"; 

    var faces = [ 
'images/img-1.jpg',
'images/img-2.jpg',
'images/img-3.jpg',
'images/img-4.jpg',
'images/img-5.jpg',
'images/img-6.jpg',
'images/img-7.jpg',
'images/img-8.jpg',
'images/img-9.jpg',
'images/img-10.jpg',
'images/img-11.jpg',
'images/img-12.jpg'
];


    function choose(card) {

            if (clicks == 12) {
                firstchoice = card;
                document.images[card].src = faces[card];
                clicks = 12;
            } 
        }

</script> but random

Comment: The drawing on part of the canvas is a separate issue. Basically I want 12 separate canvasses to be drawn on when a corresponding card is chosen